# Windows 10 to 11, then rollback to 10 broke network printing

Tags: printing, windows-11

A user upgraded to Windows 11 on a w10 Pro 21H1 Dell. I rolled it back to Windows 10, and now nothing I do will make the main printer work. There's a receipt printer that works fine, but the networked HP 4520 will not print. I can pull up the printer page in a browser with the IP address, but cannot get a test page or anything else to print. In case the problem was caused by the recent KB5006670 update, I followed all the steps to fix printing in [this Bleeping Computer Article](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/new-windows-10-kb5006670-update-breaks-network-printing/), including uninstalling the update and un-and-reinstalling the printer. None of that solved the problem. Short of reinstalling Windows and all software, does anyone have any possible solutions?

Comment: A related question at https://superuser.com/questions/1706921/windows-11-upgrade-results-in-hp-printer-either-printing-grayscale-or-failing-to/1706924#1706924 offers an alternative solution to rolling back to Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

> I rolled it back to Windows 10, and now nothing I do will make the
> main printer work.
>
> Short of reinstalling Windows and all software, does anyone have any
> possible solutions?

I would try a Windows 10 Repair Install first.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Begin with the option to Keep Everything as that normally works.
>
> The remaining 2 options (Keep only Data and your user profile; and
> Keep Nothing including not keeping your user profile) are more
> aggressive.

Comment: Thanks! The repair did a good job of keeping my data and programs, but unfortunately didn't fix my printing problem. A full reinstall did solve the problem, though.

Comment: The third option of the repair is essentially reinstalling Windows. I am glad your printing is fixed.